# Adobe AIR Native Extension : By default, does an ANE run in another thread?

Tags: multithreading, air, air-native-extension

On an iOS or Android device, does an ANE run in another thread, or would you have to start and manage a separate thread in the native extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Native Extension code in Adobe AIR for IOS run in a separate CPU Thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038436/does-native-extension-code-in-adobe-air-for-ios-run-in-a-separate-cpu-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function calls of an ANE run in the main thread. You can however start threads and use the async dispatch event command to communicate back to the Actionscript.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this one? You mean start threads from Air?

Comment: I was referring to native code here. The ane call from air is run on the main thread.